# Excluding combinations with duplicates based on a key function

Tags: python, key, combinations, python-itertools

I want to iterate over subsequences of a list, but I have a notion of uniqueness defined by an external function, and I want to ignore combinations that have multiple elements with the same value under the function.

For example, I have a list of names, and I want to iterate over all combinations of three of those names such that all three names start with different letters. The following code accomplishes this:

```
import itertools

names = ["Anabel",
         "Alison",
         "Avery",
         "Abigail",
         "Aimee",
         "Alice",
         "Bethany",
         "Beatrice",
         "Claudia",
         "Carolyn",
         "Diane",
         "Dana"]

f = lambda x : x[0]

for i in itertools.combinations(names, 3):
    if ((f(i[0]) != f(i[1])) and
        (f(i[0]) != f(i[2])) and
        (f(i[1]) != f(i[2]))):
        print i
```

What I'm actually doing here is iterating over all possible combinations of 3 names, and throwing out the ones that don't, which is of course slower than iterating over all combinations of 3 names. Is there a way that would actually be faster? To create an iterator that excludes the ones I want to skip in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, one solution I could think of requires to create a dictionary grouping the `f(value)` and the actual names as a dictionary. I'll use [`iteration_utilities.groupedby`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/groupedby.html) here but it's easy to do it yourself using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as well (I'll show it at the bottom of the answer).

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import groupedby 
>>> equivalent = groupedby(names, f)
>>> equivalent
{'A': ['Anabel', 'Alison', 'Avery', 'Abigail', 'Aimee', 'Alice'],
 'B': ['Bethany', 'Beatrice'],
 'C': ['Claudia', 'Carolyn'],
 'D': ['Diane', 'Dana']}
```

Then you iterate over the combinations of the (sorted) keys in that dictionary and then use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) to do the iterations over all names for each prefix:

```
import itertools

for comb in itertools.combinations(sorted(equivalent), 3):
    for uniquecomb in itertools.product(*[equivalent[i] for i in comb]):
        print(uniquecomb)
```

The `sorted` is used because otherwise the order of appearance wouldn't be deterministic between runs.

---

To show that this is much faster I used the following setup:

```
def unique_combs(names, f):
    equivalent = groupedby(names, f)

    for comb in itertools.combinations(sorted(equivalent), 3):
        for uniquecomb in itertools.product(*[equivalent[i] for i in comb]):
            pass

def unique_combs_original(names, f):
    for i in itertools.combinations(names, 3):
        if ((f(i[0]) != f(i[1])) and
                (f(i[0]) != f(i[2])) and
                (f(i[1]) != f(i[2]))):
            pass

names = ["Anabel", "Alison", "Avery", "Abigail", "Aimee", "Alice",
         "Bethany", "Beatrice",
         "Claudia", "Carolyn",
         "Diane", "Dana"]

f = lambda x : x[0]

%timeit unique_combs(names, f)           # 10000 loops, best of 3: 59.4 µs per loop
%timeit unique_combs_original(names, f)  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 417 µs per loop
```

But it also scales much better if there are lots of to-be-discarded combinations:

```
names = names * 10  # more duplicates

%timeit unique_combs(names, f)           # 100 loops, best of 3: 9.74 ms per loop
%timeit unique_combs_original(names, f)  # 1 loop, best of 3: 577 ms per loop
```

---

I mentioned [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of [`groupedby`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/groupedby.html), for completness it can be created like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

>>> names = ["Anabel", "Alison", "Avery", "Abigail", "Aimee", "Alice",
...          "Bethany", "Beatrice",
...         "Claudia", "Carolyn",
...         "Diane", "Dana"]

>>> equivalent = defaultdict(list)
>>> for name in names:
...     equivalent[f(name)].append(name)

>>> equivalent
defaultdict(list,
            {'A': ['Anabel', 'Alison', 'Avery', 'Abigail', 'Aimee', 'Alice'],
             'B': ['Bethany', 'Beatrice'],
             'C': ['Claudia', 'Carolyn'],
             'D': ['Diane', 'Dana']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from `itertools` for following one-liner:

```
[p for c in combinations((tuple(g) for _, g in groupby(names, lambda x: x[0])), 3) 
       for p in product(*c)]
```

In above `groupby` groups the names based on the first letter and returns iterable of `(key, group)` tuples. Each `group` is an iterable itself which is then converted to tuple so that it can be iterated over many times. Note that this assumes that names starting with same letter are next to each other in the list. If this is not the case you can sort the names before using `groupby`.

Here's an example of `groupby` by itself:

```
>>> groups = list(tuple(g) for _, g in groupby(names, lambda x: x[0]))
>>> groups
[('Anabel', 'Alison', 'Avery', 'Abigail', 'Aimee', 'Alice'), ('Bethany', 'Beatrice'), ('Claudia', 'Carolyn'), ('Diane', 'Dana')]
```

Next the result groups are given to `combinations` which will return all the subsequences from groups with 3 elements in them:

```
>>> combs = list(combinations(groups, 3))
>>> combs
[(('Anabel', 'Alison', 'Avery', 'Abigail', 'Aimee', 'Alice'), ('Bethany', 'Beatrice'), ('Claudia', 'Carolyn')), (('Anabel', 'Alison', 'Avery', 'Abigail', 'Aimee', 'Alice'), ('Bethany', 'Beatrice'), ('Diane', 'Dana')), (('Anabel', 'Alison', 'Avery', 'Abigail', 'Aimee', 'Alice'), ('Claudia', 'Carolyn'), ('Diane', 'Dana')), (('Bethany', 'Beatrice'), ('Claudia', 'Carolyn'), ('Diane', 'Dana'))]
```

Finally each combination is unpacked and passed to `product` that will produce the cartesian product for the given groups:

```
>>> result = list(p for c in combs for p in product(*c))
>>> result[0]
('Anabel', 'Bethany', 'Claudia')
>>> len(result)
80
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is fascinating, but there's enough that I'm unfamiliar with that I can't really unpack what's going on here.

Comment: Just nitpicking: It's not actually a one-liner if you write it over two lines :-) However very clever use of `itertools.groupby` if the input is already sorted.

Comment: Also it's a bit slower than my solution - however I can't exactly figure out why given that the actual processing is identical (just that `groupby` replaces the dictionary I used).

Comment: @Jacob: Added explanation, hope it clarifies what's going on.

Comment: @MSeifert: That's interesting, what if you only test `groupby` vs `groupedby` and exclude all the other processing?

Comment: hard to test because one creates a dictionary and the other one an iterator. But superfically timing it shows they should be equally fast.